# Is there a faster way to pull in JSON Data than dataWithContentsOfURL?

Tags: objective-c, json, rest, optimization, nsdata

I am building an app that requires JSON data. I am using a get call to a RESTful API and using and NSJSONSerialization to go through the data. In an effort to reduce start up time, I am logging the time everything takes to complete. After putting in the following log statements around this code, I noticed that this single call is taking on average exactly 5 seconds to complete. Any way that I can improve this time? I'm only getting 100 posts via JSON, so I can't imagine this is the fastest that it can move. Here is the code:

```
NSLog(@"Data Retrieval STARTED");
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:getURL]];
NSLog(@"Data Pull ENDED");
```

When I view the log, The first Log statement and the 2nd are always 5 seconds apart, so there's my test, not as accurate as Time Profiler, but I trust it. Tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should establish with curl (or similar) a baseline to compare the 5sec time to.  Until then, I'd assume it's the server+transaction and nothing special related to iOS.

Anyway, no matter the delay, a remote request is too long to do synchronously while the app blocks.  Instead, start by defining what amusing / useful thing your UI can do during the request (Maybe its a just spinner, or maybe its other startup tasks. Be thoughtful about this).  Then create an `NSURLRequest` from the `NSURL` and pass that to an `NSURLConnection` using:

```
+ (void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse*, NSData*, NSError*))handler
```

In the completion block, parse the response and restore your UI to "ready".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:` instead. For the option parameter, pass in `NSDataReadingUncached`, this will improve performance if your data is being read only once and then discarded

Second Solution:

Open a connection using `NSUrlConnection` before hand, then when you are getting the JSON file, there is no extra time taken to open the connection first.

Comment: This didn't make it go any faster

Comment: If you request it from somewhere else like another program does it go faster?

Comment: I mean it goes quicker if I make less JSON calls, like 50 instead of 100

Comment: Sometimes it maybe a server side problem, that's why I'm asking.